# Select and group by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores the number of users who score in a particular range. I am trying to design a query that will show the total number of students who scored in that range. The table has repetitions since its a log table. here is there table

[image]

Here is my query

```
select id, min, max, count(Score) 
from Scorelogs
```

I know I have to use "COUNT" in the query but I don't know how to group by the min and max.

Answer (score 2):

You want to just group by the range:

```
select "min", "max", sum(score)
from data
group by "min", "max"
order by 1, 2;
```

Note that `min` and `max` are very poor names for columns, because they conflict with the built in functions that have the same names.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I should have been using sum()

Answer (score 1):

Use as , In this scenerio id is not generated.

```
select min,max, count(Score) from Scorelogs group by min,max
```

Or you can use

```
 select ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY max) AS id, min,max, count(Score) from Scorelogs group by min,max
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY min,max) as id, 
       min,
       max, 
       SUM(Score) 
FROM   Scorelogs 
GROUP BY min,max
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5067f/2)**